# Keep loosing audio output (time to reinstall XP?)

Tags: sound

I've very frustrated with xubuntu, like it but it keep loosing sound.  About ready to throw in the towel, zap disc & reinstall MS XP!!!

Checked sound not muted on PA Volume Control!!

Help.....

Comment: Please give more details about your setup. Your soundcard, and the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: Found this on forums, re-install sound!! Worked for me:-sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

Answer (score 1):

Worked for OP:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
```